# HTML5 History API Implementation

Tags: javascript, html, history

This might sound like a duplicate, but I have searched through the forum questions and I haven't found what I was looking for.

So, I have been reading for a while now, and I still cannot decide what to do about the next situation. I'm building a one page website ( not my first ) which requires a smooth User Interface, so I have decide to load pages with AJAX for a better and more friendly navigation.

I have been using : [SmartAjax](http://codecanyon.net/item/smartajax-smart-powerful-and-easy-to-setup-ajax/406189) ; for a while and it was good enough for me. It works nicely and I had no problems with it, but with it had problems handling a lot of JavaScript as callback. Also there was a lot of work to do when implementing it through the whole website.

And because now HTML5 is more stable than it was one year ago, and most of it's features are working in most of the browsers ( but some still require a polyfill ), I decided to start using HTML5 History API. A lot of websites use it and it's very easy to do so, but there some aspects I don't understand about it.

Therefore here's what I would like to know about it :

- is it supported by all browsers by now, and most important, will touch devices and mobiles support it ?
- is there a special library or a framework for it ?
- is it safe to use for small websites ( a maximum of 6 pages ) but with a lot of JavaScript ?
- does it behave when using it in combination with jQuery Plugins ?
- what about hashbang and hashes ? aren't they the same as using History API ? and what are the differences ?

I would appreciate all the help and info I get about the points stated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Browser support**

[Forget it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history). Not even IE 9 supports `history.pushState`. Mobile browsers not very safe either. But there is a library (see below) that makes this incompatibility completely transparent to the developer.

**Library**

Well, in pure HTML 5 environments, the history api is pretty straightforward. For others, the [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) library has gotten quite some attention, plus it offers an automated fallback to the old hash-writing

**On Small Websites**

Well, you better have your JavaScript and your potential States organised, then. But if so, I see no problem.

**History & jQuery & plugins**

I have used the two together in a couple of projects now. I have not yet found any problem with using jQuery and jQuery Plugins, except for - of course - the typical issues associated with Injected HTML (i.e. event handlers must be rebound; `$(document).ready()` might or might not work in some environments, etc).

**Hashes vs. history.pushState**

The Hash-Notation has been used as a workaround (or nowadays, fallback). It becomes unnecessary when using history.pushState.

What I have found to be the major difference is, that the URL in the address bar is always directly understandable by the server, especially for bookmarking or link-sharing purposes. If you had http://example.org/#/my/fancy/site, then your index page would have to parse the hash (via javascript, as you can't access the hash server-side), and then inject/redirect to `my/fancy/site`.

However, if using using history.pushState, the Browser's address bar shows http://example.org/my/fancy/site - which is directly routable.

(and, imagine spelling out a hash, or hash-bang URL to someone via phone!)

Hope that clarifies some or your doubts with history! I can strongly recommend History.js as library a of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use HTML5 History for browsers which support it (all current browsers and upcoming IE10), and use just static (non-Ajax) links for older ones. As browsers are updated, your site gets better automatically.

I wouldn't recommend using hash polyfills due to serious disadvantages of hashes (e.g. pointless referers that don't include hash part of URL, thus making stats rather useless).